# Pass values based on different select option

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I'm trying to get different values based on the options user select from the dropdown. 
eg. when user select option 1 from dropdown => pass value 111 to .$numbers in form

How do i do that? What code should i be including in the //some code area?

```
switch($_POST['outlet']){
    case 'a' : 
        //some code;
        //get value 111 from here
        break;
    case 'b':
        //some code;
        //get value 222 from here
        break;
    case 'c':
        //some code;
        //get value 333 from here
        break;
    default:
        //some code if the post doesn't match anything
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the values to the `option` from the `select`? `<option value="111">1</option>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
<select id="sc" name="outlet">
        <option value="111">1</option>
        <option value="222">2</option>
    </select>

    <select id="sh" name="outlet">
        <option value="333">3</option>
        <option value="444">4</option>
    </select>

    <select id="sw" name="outlet">
        <option value="555">5</option>
        <option value="666">6</option>
    </select>

    Then, just take the value of $_POST['outlet']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$numbers = null;
switch($_POST['outlet']){
    case 'a' : 
        //some code;
        //get value 111 from here
        $numbers = 111;
        break;
    case 'b':
        //some code;
        //get value 222 from here
        $numbers = 222;
        break;
    case 'c':
        //some code;
        //get value 333 from here
        $numbers = 333;
        break;
    default:
        //some code if the post doesn't match anything
        break;
}

echo is_null($numbers) ? 'Numbers is null' : $numbers; // <- correct value
```